# Measuring the distance between two points electrically

Tags: ultrasound, transceiver, distance

I am trying to build a real time location system(RTLS). I have a arena of 10 x 10 meters in dimension. And would like to track the position of the object moving in the arena with a precision of within few centimeters (5 cm tolerance say). I could attach a transceiver with the moveable object if I like. Besides the moveable object there could other object scattered or erected in the arena. I know if I could measure distance of the object from at least 3 predefined positions, I could solve equations to find the coordinate of the object.

The problem I am into is the method to find the distance of an object from any fixed place.

What could be the best method to use considering the accuracy required and working dimensions of the arena minimizing the cost?

Answer (score 1):

If I had access to the space above the arena I'd use a video camera to track a bright LED mounted on top of the object.

Comment: On a bright sunny day, I don't think I will have luck with this method, knowing that the object could have a shiny surface to reflect light which may shine brighter than the LED's

Comment: On a bright, sunny day you'd still have the image of the device captured and, knowing its dimensions, it shouldn't be too difficult to determine the position of any part of it with respect to the arena's bounds. Then, of course, there's always the [alternate solution](http://www.amazon.com/Krylon-51602-Interior-Exterior-Decorator/dp/B000B8UPHE)

Answer (score 0):

You need to triangulate its position, you could have stationary receivers, then have your movable object emit signals. You record the strengths of the signals to the receivers when it is in a known position, perhaps between the two or three receivers such that they form a straight line and then as the object moves in the x or y direction the signal to the receivers will vary depending on the angle the moving object makes. The receivers will also have to communicate since they need to synchronize the strength of the signals. If my suggestion does not meet your needs just google triangulation (also how earthquake strengths are measured).